# Multiple Autocomplete function Open render previous items

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm having a litle problem with my autocomplete. I'm using two autocompletes in same page.
In both I'm rendering my elements from ajax (diferente sources), and also in both, i'm using the _render option to show my elements.
The problem is: In my second autocomplete, in the funcion Open I want use the $('.ui-autocomplete > li') but when I do this, it will return the new ones, but also with the li elements from the previous autocomplete...
This is my second autocomplete:

```
$(".chooseProduct").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            ....
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item != null)
            selectedProduct(ui.item);
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        //this length will return the newest and the other elements :(
        var len = $('.ui-autocomplete > li').length;
        if (!(len == 8 && showQtd > 8)) {
            if ((len % 8) == 0) {
                $('.ui-autocomplete').append("<li class='ui-menu-item'><a>------Show more------</a></li>");
            }
        }
        else showQtd = 8;
    }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    var extra = "";
    if (item.dosagem != null)
        extra = "DOS: " + item.dosagem + " ";

    return $('<li></li>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append('<a>COD: <b>' + item.codigo + ' ' + item.name + '</b>' + item.pvp + '<br/>' + extra + '</a>')
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

How can I instead of using $('.ui-autocomplete > li') use only my returned elements?
Thanks

Comment: Can you demonstrate what your trying to do in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the selector `$('ui-element > li)` it will render all the items that are included in the element that you define to do autocomplete. To obtain the current elements (the elements that are being rendered by this autocomplete) do this way:

```
var len = $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element.children().length;
```

To get all elements:

```
var elements = $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element.children();
```